# Selecting lines intersecting lines on two points in QGIS 3.14

Tags: qgis, intersection, linestring, virtual-layer

I have two shapes of lines: one A with exploded red lines, the other B with closed black lines.

In a virtual layer I want to select the yellow ones (A) i.e. those having only 2 points in common with B.

I try to find a way to count the number of intersections between 2 lines without success.

Or maybe there is a better way to do it.

[image]

[image]

---

@JGH There is something weird when I work with my data. I can't get the result you show on your screenshot.    When I run the query to get the same result as you:

```
SELECT poly.*
FROM input1 as poly, input2 AS ouverture 
WHERE st_intersects(poly.geometry, ouverture.geometry)
AND st_dimension(st_intersection(poly.geometry, ouverture.geometry)) = 0
```

Then the result is the **red** lines :
[image]

The green polygons (poly) have only 4 nodes and topology is correct with black lines.    It runs from a model so green polygon file converted to lines is not visible.
The strangest are the two red lines at the bottom which are the opposite of the expected result.

@Taras : result is empty.

EDIT : [sample of data](https://we.tl/t-NQU2ihVgek)
shp and comments inside.

Comment: it would be a good idea to provide a reference to a fragment of the original geodata so that potential defendants can simulate your original situation...

Comment: Can you share a piece of data with us? Would be useful

Comment: I added a sample of data, a comment file and a model for Qgis. The main problem for now is the result of the intersection operator.

Comment: Please edit you your question

Comment: BTW, what is the diffrence between *data_source* and *data_work*?

Comment: data _source is for model. data_work is data_work after some process and ready for JGH query. Read the comment file will help or it is not clear at all :(.

Comment: You will want to add vertices to the black lines where they meet the yellow lines (or the source green polygons). While you claim that the two datasets are topologically correct, it is doubtful without vertices at the intersection points (likely due to coordinate rounding errors, floating point imprecision etc)

Comment: I used S and T tools from Qgis to digitize and even used advanced digitizing tools. How did you draw your example ?

Comment: @Leehan I first added vertices on the black lines, then connected them to make the yellow lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select the line that intersect the box, then you compute the intersection and keep only the ones who have an intersection composed of points (i.e. exclude the intersection made of lines)

```sql
SELECT tg.*
FROM target_layer AS tg, closes_line_layer AS cl 
WHERE st_intersects(tg.geometry, cl.geometry)
AND ST_Dimension(st_intersection(tg.geometry, cl.geometry)) = 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT r.*
FROM "red_lines" AS r, "black_lines" AS b 
WHERE st_within(start_point(r.geometry), b.geometry)
AND st_within(end_point(r.geometry), b.geometry)
AND st_length(st_intersection(r.geometry, b.geometry)) = 0
```

Comment: All lines are selected, not only the yellow ones. But it may be a good start.

Comment: Are they also lines, I mean those yellows?

Comment: yes. The two shapefiles are lines. We need a criteria : "select when there is  **only** startpoint and endpoint on lines (not more)".

Comment: please check updates

Comment: selection is empty with `st_intersection`. If it can help, blacklines can be polygons since they are closed.

Comment: What do you mean by *black lines can be polygons*, is it a geometry Collection, pure Polygons or Polylines though?

Comment: At the start, black_lines shapefile is a polygon one. I convert it into polyline just because I was trying some ways to make my query. But I can work with black "lines" shapefile of polygon or polyline depending on what is needed for the query to work.